# Minesweeper grid representation + calculating neighbor-sums

Tags: python, minesweeper

I'm trying to get better at Python and would like a critique.

Problem statement:

> Accept a 2D grid containing 1's and 0's (1 being mine locations) and
>   print a *solved sum* grid (the way the final grid would show upon
>   completion of a minesweeper game with all the neighbor sums).

Beyond that, what might be horribly wrong with the code below?  I am interested in finding a recommended balance between readability and what the cool kids call *idiomatic*. For example, List comprehension in some places was deliberately omitted in favor of making something that I thought was easier on the eyes.

The top-level functions are called via:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    locMap = [[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1]] # Sample input
    print "Location map = "
    printMineField(locMap,locMap)
    newMap = getSummedMap(locMap)
    print "Summed map = "
    printMineField(locMap,newMap)
```

The output is:

> ```
> '''
>
> Location map =
> * 0 0 0
> 0 0 * 0
> 0 * 0 *
>
> Summed map =
> * 2 1 1
> 2 3 * 2
> 1 * 3 *
>
> '''
> ```

The actual functions are:

```
def generatePaddedGrid(grid):
    """
    Input: 2D list.
    Output: 2D list
    Purpose: Returns a 0-padded boundary around a grid.  Useful to perform
    easier 2D traversal + operations of the inner grid without painful
    boundary checking
    """

    # Get Dimensions of grid
    nRows = len(grid)
    nCols = len(grid[0])

    # Create a grid with +2 row/col padding (on all sides)
    paddedGrid = [[0 for x in range(0,nCols + 2)] for x in range(0,nRows + 2)]

    # Insert 'centered' locMap into the Padded Grid
    for xIter in range(0,nRows):
        for yIter in range(0,nCols):
            paddedGrid[xIter+1][yIter+1] = grid[xIter][yIter]

    return paddedGrid

def getSummedMap(locMap):
    """
    Input: 2D list
    Output: 2D list
    Purpose: Takes in a 2D array (locMap)   and returns a same-sized array
    with each cell now containing the sum of all the neighbors including
    diagonals (max of 8 neigbor cells)
    """

    # Insert + Center this grid into a padded grid to prevent access errors
    paddedGrid = generatePaddedGrid(locMap)


    nRows = len(locMap)  #Actual rows to be iterated
    nCols = len(locMap[0]) #Actual cols to be iterated.

   # Create a target/output grid of the actual size to write the sums into
    sumGrid = [[0 for x in range(0,nCols)] for y in range(0,nRows)]

    for xIter in range(1,nRows+1):
        for yIter in range(1,nCols+1):
            Sum = 0
            # Top + Bottom + Left + right
            Sum  += paddedGrid[xIter-1][yIter] +\
                    paddedGrid[xIter+1][yIter] +\
                    paddedGrid[xIter][yIter+1] +\
                    paddedGrid[xIter][yIter-1]

            # Then 4 diagonals
            Sum  += paddedGrid[xIter-1][yIter-1] +\
                    paddedGrid[xIter+1][yIter-1] +\
                    paddedGrid[xIter+1][yIter+1] +\
                    paddedGrid[xIter-1][yIter+1]


            sumGrid[xIter-1][yIter-1] = Sum

    return sumGrid


def printMineField(locMap, SumMap):
    """
    Input: 2 x 2D Arrays
    Output: No return, just print an overlayed Sum-map over a given Loc-map
    but leave the mine-locations as '*' (instead of the neighbor-sums)
    """

    numActualRows = len(locMap)  #Actual rows to be iterated
    numActualCols = len(locMap[0]) #Actual cols to be iterated.

    for xIter in range(0,numActualRows):
        for yIter in range(0,numActualCols):
            if locMap[xIter][yIter] == 1:
                print '*',
            else:
                print str(SumMap[xIter][yIter]),
        print '\n'
```

Comment: take a look at numpy and strides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea ... in your getSummedMap function, you could put all the +1, -1, 0's in a list of 2-tuples and get the Sum with one for loop, e.g. ...

```
neighbor_incs = [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1),  # Top + Bottom + Left + right
                 (-1, -1), (1, -1), (1, 1), (-1, 1), ] # diagonals

for x_inc, y_inc in neighbor_incs:
    Sum += paddedGrid[xIter + x_inc][yIter + y_inc]
```